# Solve $u''(t)+2u'(t)+2u(t)=f(t), \ t\geq 0, \ u(0)=1, \ u'(0)=0$ using Laplace Transforms.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Use Laplace Transforms to give a solution formula for the initial
>   value problem
>
> $$u''(t)+2u'(t)+2u(t)=f(t), \ t\geq 0, \ u(0)=1, \ u'(0)=0. \tag1$$
>
> where $f$ is a function such that $|f(t)|\leq Ate^B$ for some
>   $A,B\in\mathbb{R}.$

Taking the LT of both sides I end upp with

$$\tilde{u}(s^2+2s+2)=\tilde{f}+s+2\implies\tilde{u}=\frac{\tilde{f}+s+2}{s^2+2s+2} = \frac{\tilde{f}+s+2}{(s+1)^2+1}, \tag2$$

where tilde denotes the laplace transform. I really have no idea how to proceed after this. Nowhere in my table can I see something that resembles the RHS in $(2)$ so I can't use any inversion formula.

**EDIT 1:**

Ok I actually got it now I think. Just need to split the last fraction up and complete the square of the denominator...

**EDIT 2:**

And I'm now stuck here:

$$\tilde{u}=\frac{\tilde{f}}{(s+1)+1}+\frac{s+1}{(s+1)+1}+\frac{1}{(s+1)+1}.$$

There is a formula that says that $L(e^{ct}f(t))=F(s-c),$ $c\in\mathbb{C.}$ But I don't see how it's applicable here...

Comment: $\mathcal L \{Ate^{B}\} = Ae^B \mathcal L\{t\} = \frac {Ae^B}{s^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\bar u=\frac{\tilde{f}+s+2}{(s+1)^2+1} = \frac{\tilde{f}}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{s+2}{(s+1)^2+1}
$$

then using the suitable inversion tables

$$
u(t) =((\cos t+\sin t)e^{-t}+f * ( e^{-t}\sin t))\phi(t)
$$

where $\phi(t)$ is the unit step function and $\cdot * \cdot$ is the convolution operator

Comment: I don't see which suitable inversion formulas you're using.

Comment: Ok I figured it out now. Thank you!

Comment: @Isham $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}\right) = (e^{-t}\sin t)\phi(t)$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s+2}{(s+1)^2+1}\right)  = ((\cos t+\sin t)e^{-t})\phi(t)$

Comment: I see thanks cesareo